# Given $A,B,C$ with certain relations find $P(A)$

Tags: probability

Suppose events $A$, $B$, $C$ satisfy the following conditions:
$A$ and $B$-complement ($\bar{B}$) are mutually exclusive, $B$ and $C$-complement ($\bar{C}$) are mutually exclusive, $P(\bar{A}∩B)=0.2$, $P(\bar{B}∩C)=0.15$, and $P(C)=0.6$. Find $P(A)$.

I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know demorgans laws?

Comment: I would start by drawing a Venn diagram with three interlocking rings representing A, B and C. Then I'd black certain areas out to indicate that they're ruled out due to the mutual exclusivity information, and I'd fill in numerical info.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a Venn diagram. Then intuitively, the first two conditions tells us that $A$ is nested in $B$, which is nested in $C$. So $P(A) = 0.6 - 0.15 - 0.2 = 0.25$. Using symbols:
\begin{align*}
P(C) &= P(B \cap C) + P(\overline B \cap C) \\
0.6 &= P(B) - P(B \cap \overline C) + 0.15 \\
0.6 &= P(B) - 0 + 0.15 &\text{since $B$ and $C$ complement are mutually exclusive}\\
0.45 &= P(A \cap B) + P(\overline A \cap B) \\
0.45 &= P(A) - P(A \cap \overline B) + 0.2 \\
0.45 &= P(A) - 0 + 0.2 &\text{since $A$ and $B$ complement are mutually exclusive}\\
P(A) &= 0.25
\end{align*}

Comment: I tried to draw ven diagram
how whould it look like

Comment: Draw a circle that represents $A$. Now since $A \cap \overline B =\emptyset$, we know that $A \subseteq B$, so to represent $B$, draw a bigger circle around $A$. Likewise, since $B \cap \overline C = \emptyset$, we know that $B \subseteq C$, so to represent $C$, draw a bigger circle around $B$.

Comment: Cool. I just draw it. thank you very much for the help